# Exception message: Undefined variable:

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm trying to retrieve data from mysql database using laravel. It shows error `undefined variable`

view.blade.php

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Body</th>
    <th>Category</th>
  </tr>
  @foreach($post as $row)
  <tr>
    <td>{{$row['title']}}</td>
    <td>{{$row['body']}}</td>
    <td>{{$row['category_id']}}</td>
  </tr>
  @endforeach
</table>
```

postController code

```
 public function index()
    {
        $post = posts::all()->toArray();
        return view('view',compact('post'));
    }
```

I expect it to show result for my database table but it shows error `Undefined variable`

Comment: What's the return of `$post`?

Comment: Undefined variable: post (View: D:\xampp\htdocs\app3\resources\views\view.blade.php)

Comment: are you sure posts is model

Comment: i didn't get your point

Comment: posts is your model or not?

Comment: no i didn't create model

Comment: $post = posts::all()->toArray();   so tell me whats meaning of posts. you wrote on code.

Comment: posts is table in database

Comment: no dear, you first create model. wait i will my update my answer. check on @romil

Comment: Please always include the _complete_ error message including what file and on what line it's complaining about. You should also then point out the line in your posted code.

Comment: check my updated code  @romil

Comment: I've voted to close this questions for not including the complete error message (which is crucial, since we don't actually know if the posted code is related to the error or not).

Answer (score 2):

First go to project folder via cmd then,

```
php artisan make:model Posts.
```

You will get created file in `App` folder with the name `Posts.php`

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Posts extends Model
{
    protected $table   = 'posts';

    protected $fillable = [
        'title', 'body','category_id'
    ];
}
```

Don't forget to include namespace of your model at the top of your controller like:

```
use App\Posts;
```

and then in your index method,

```
public function index()
{
    $post = Posts::all();

    return view('your_views_correct_path',compact('post'));
}
```

Don't need to pass your post collection by converting it to array to view. Simply pass post as shown above.
Then you can easily access post attribute by looping post collection in `foreach` loop.

```
@if(!empty($post))

    @foreach($post as $p)
        {{ $p->title }} // for title
        {{ $p->body }} // for body and so on
    @endforeach
@else
    <p>Post are empty.</p>
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

**you returning home blade file but using  $post variable in view.blade.php file.
return view.blade.php file in controller**

```
 $post = posts::all();
    return view('view')->with(['post'=>$post]);
```

Comment: now i'm returning view blade but problem still exists

Comment: <?php $__currentLoopData = $post; $__env->addLoop($__currentLoopData); foreach($__currentLoopData as $row): $__env->incrementLoopIndices(); $loop = $__env->getLastLoop(); ?>

Comment: dd($post); i think it is empty

Answer (score 0):

```
in cmd :  php artisan make:model Posts
then check App/ Posts.
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Posts extends Model
{
     protected $table   = 'posts';

    protected $fillable = [
        'title', 'body','category_id'
    ];
}



then  in Controller
  public function index()
        {
            $post = Posts::all();

            return view('view',compact('post'));
        }
```

Comment: check your controller, routes, And view.blade.php

Comment: and try dd($post);  after   $post = posts::get(); all data shown or not